# Used Cabinets for Kitchen Remodel?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, remodel

[image]We're very seriously considering buying used kraftmaid kitchen cabinets. They're in good condition and have been professionally removed from previous kitchen.

The cabinets are white with a blue island. We will need to purchase a few new pieces to complete our layout. Do you know how difficult it is to purchase or find cabinets to match the old cabinets?

Pictures of some of the cabinets pasted below. Price for cabinets, range hood, some appliances, and countertops is $3200.

Would love to hear about your experience using used cabinets, including the good or the bad.

Thanks for your help!
[image]

[image]

Comment: I’d look closely at the hardware: drawer slides and hinges can get gunked up and not perform adequately. These can be replaced, but it’s all part of the cost/benefit equation.

Comment: Most newer cabinets are sprayed with a conversion varnish. Talk to a local cabinet maker and ask them if they use  conversion varnish and can color match stuff for you.

Comment: Why is this question closed. This is not arts and crafts. This is a legitimate question about kitchen cabinets and does not ask "What color should I use?" This is far more about home improvement than the question above about statistics on kilowatt solar panels or whatever the heck they were asking about.

Answer (score 3):

Using used cabinets is a risk.
Some may be in good condition, others in the same set can be a mess. Then fitment can be a challenge because the cabinets were not designed for the space they are being used in.

That said, if the cabinets are in good shape and you have patience you can build a nice layout.

Any cabinet can be painted. Find a good paint store that is willing to paint match the cabinets. You may be able to get touch up kits from the manufacturer, but a good paint pro can be your savior.  Find someone that has the knowledge of what paint is needed for that cabinet finish and is willing to work to get a close to perfect match.

Get fill strips. These are pieces that fill in the spaces between the cabinets and the walls or between the cabinets when spacing is needed, ( like at corners)  You may not be able to get the exact color fill strip, so again the paint match is important.

Before hanging, check if any boxes need reinforced. They can get damaged or weakened when being taken down.  Do any repairs and reinforcements before installation.

Finally, don't expect the cabinets to be perfect. They are used so there will be some imperfections.

Answer (score 3):

It depends:

1. Are you installing the cabinets yourself, or paying someone to do it? If you are paying someone to to do it, the extra work required to fit the old cabinets in the new space might cost more than getting new cabinets that fit your space. Make sure to speak with the person installing them before you pay for the old cabinets.
2. What's the style of your house and kitchen? If you have an old house with an eclectic style (e.g. things don't match), then used cabinets can look better and fit the house better than new cabinets.
3. How much money are the used cabinets? I would not pay more than 10% of the retail price. Most people who get used cabinets get them for free. I get offered used kitchen cabinets on a regular basis (same for exercise equipment), because people just want their old stuff hauled away. When I remodel kitchens, I consider the hassle of giving them away to be more than the dump fee. So for many people, used kitchen cabinets have a negative dollar value.
4. Are you painting them yourself, and do you enjoy painting? Painting cabinets is a lot more than applying the paint. But if you are up for it, totally worth it, and if done properly, the final product will look great. Ask for estimates for painting the cabinets before you buy the used ones. The cost of painting them might be more than buying new cabinets.